# calling function each time any change is detected `.change()`

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have many elements on my page. They are bind to change event. I think there are such 30 elements.

One such:

```
$("#set-angle").change(function(){
    //...do stuff
});
```

Now I want to call `globalChangeFunc` each time any such .change() is fcalled on any element.
I know it is possible. I have used it in `Backbone`. But to detect the same in JQuery.

Small snippet of Backbone:

```
// Removes just the `onChange` callback.
object.off("change", onChange);

// Removes all "change" callbacks.
object.off("change");

// Removes the `onChange` callback for all events.
object.off(null, onChange);

// Removes all callbacks for `context` for all events.
object.off(null, null, context);

// Removes all callbacks on `object`.
object.off();
```

Something similar to this.

Comment: What would you have done in underscore? Did you just try to do that in jQuery? Did it work or did it give an error?

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique, you cannot/shouldn't have 30 elements with same ID

Comment: @epascarello, this time my project doesn't use Underscore and I don't want to include it merely for this thing

Comment: @A.Wolff: that I know, that's why i wrote `One such`.

Comment: @softvar I was not saying to do it WITH underscore. I was saying apply what you would have done with underscore to jQuery.

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly wrote underscore, it's in Backbone. See the updated question. I apologize!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#set-angle").change(globalChangeFunc);
```

---

assign a class to all elements you want change event.

```
$(".change_me").change(globalChangeFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without more info, the most generic solution I can come up with is this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input, select, textarea', function(){
    globalChangeFunc();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign css class to all that elements (`#set-angle` element will also have `.x` class) like:

```
$(".x").change(function(){
    globalChangeFunc();
    //...do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use id's(dont tell me you will assign 30 diff id's).Instead assign a common class.*$(this)* takes care of all your worries.

I am assuming that you have to assign a function only to the element undergoing change.

```
$.fn.globalChangeFunc= function(){   
        //some code   
};

$(document).on('change','.class',function(){
$(this).globalChangeFunc();
});
```

If its a common function,i.e not for specific element:

```
  function globalChangeFunc(){...}

  $(document).on('change','.class',function(){
        globalChangeFunc();
    });
```

Update:

Give four ids to your sliders.Detect those on click and take action by passing arguments to a common function.

```
$(document).on('change', '.class', function () {
switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
    case 'up':
        $(this).globalChangeFunc(appropriate params);
        break;
    case 'down':
        $(this).globalChangeFunc(appropriate params);
        break;
    case 'right':
        $(this).globalChangeFunc(appropriate params);
        break;
    case 'left':
        $(this).globalChangeFunc(appropriate params);
        break;
   }
});
```

Comment: this exactly what i said..Assign a common class..see the first solution..That will take care of what you want without assigning 30 diff ids..Besides,your giving ids to your element is not a false solution its just that there is a better and a simpler solution that you are not trying.the one with classes.Assigning this many ids is definately not the best of code conventions..

Comment: i am busy with something ,i will reply in a while..but its pretty easy...just use a switch case and detect which part(up,dow,top,bot) was clicked